# jquery $() and document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

why is it that

```
var drop = document.getElementById('sidebar-left');
if(drop.addEventListener) {
    drop.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragover, false);
    drop.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragover, false);
    drop.addEventListener('drop', dropIn, false);
}
```

works, but

```
var drop = $('sidebar-left')[0];
if(drop.addEventListener) {
    drop.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragover, false);
    drop.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragover, false);
    drop.addEventListener('drop', dropIn, false);
}
```

doesn't work? As far as I know, both should work.

Comment: $('sidebar-left') should be $('#sidebar-left')

Comment: `$('sidebar-left')` would look for a DOM tag of `<sidebar-left>`

Comment: As a side note, the first method is preferred since you're not using any of jQuery's features with the matched element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery `$` function expects a CSS selector, not an ID.

`$('sidebar-left')` should be `$('#sidebar-left')`

You might be confusing it with the Prototype.js `$` function which expects an ID.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery method doesn't work because you missed the `#` in the selector:

```
var drop = $('#sidebar-left')[0];
```

At the moment it is attempting to get the DOM element of an empty jQuery object, which will return `undefined`.

To convert the entire snippet to jQuery, try this:

```
var $drop = $('#sidebar-left');
$drop.on('dragenter', handleDragover);
$drop.on('dragover', handleDragover);
$drop.on('drop', dropIn);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('sidebar-left')
```

should have been

> `$('#sidebar-left')`

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers, mine is the same: jQuery expects a CSS-style selector (ref: Sizzle). One thing to note however, is that you don't need to use `[0]` if you're looking for something by ID (as opposed to class) because it will only return one object. Unless, you're using the same ID on multiple elements...but I don't think you would be doing that...

Recap, `$('#sidebar-left')`

Comment: He's using the `[0]` to extract the DOM element so that `addEventListener` can be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('sidebar-left')
```

is trying to find all  elements, not the element with the sidebar-left id. You want

```
$('#sidebar-left')
```